# Why can I only do 2 concurrent downloads with the .NET GDrive API v3?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-drive-api

I'm not sure if this is a client or an API limitation, but I can't seem to do more than 2 concurrent downloads with the .NET GDrive API. This causes a big problem for my application, because if the user wants to download more than 2 files at once, all the other "queued" downloads will timeout eventually if the first 2 downloads aren't completed in time, which will also raise a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskWasCanceled` in my case, since I'm using `FilesResource.GetRequest.DownloadAsync`.

Is there some sort of property that I can change to allow more than 2 concurrent downloads, or to increase the timeout before it raises an exception?

Here's my current download function:

```
public static async Task DownloadFile(string name, string downloadPath, string extractPath, string appExePath, GridButton clickedGridBtn)
{
    name += ".zip";
    downloadPath += ".zip";

    foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File gDriveFile in filesList)
    {
        if (!gDriveFile.Name.Equals(name))
            continue;

        Utils.CreateDirIfNotExist(ConfigUtils.downloadPath);

        clickedGridBtn.Btn.IsEnabled = false;

        DownloadProgressPanel dlProgressPanel = new DownloadProgressPanel() { AppIconPath = $"/Resources/Icons/{name.Replace(".zip", string.Empty)}" };
        UIElementCollection dlProgressWindowChildren = MainWindow.Instance.DlProgressPanelStack.Children;
        bool alreadyExists = false;

        foreach (DownloadProgressPanel dlPanel in dlProgressWindowChildren)
        {
            if (dlPanel.AppIconPath.Equals(dlProgressPanel.AppIconPath))
            {
                int index = dlProgressWindowChildren.IndexOf(dlPanel);

                dlProgressWindowChildren.RemoveAt(index);
                dlProgressWindowChildren.Insert(index, dlProgressPanel);

                alreadyExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyExists)
            dlProgressWindowChildren.Add(dlProgressPanel);

        MainWindow.Instance.TabButton_Click(MainWindow.Instance.DownloadsTabBtn);

        FileStream dlFileStream = new FileStream(downloadPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        FilesResource.GetRequest fileReq = service.Files.Get(gDriveFile.Id);
        long? fileSize = gDriveFile.Size;

        dlProgressPanel.DownloadSizeText.Text = $"Downloading... 0 MB of {Utils.ConvertToGigabytes(fileSize)}";
        dlProgressPanel.DLProgressBar.Value = Utils.ConvertToPercentage(0.0, (double)fileSize);

        fileReq.MediaDownloader.ChunkSize = 204800;
        fileReq.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                    UpdateProgressValues(progress, fileSize, dlProgressPanel);
                    break;
                case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                    UpdateProgressValues(progress, fileSize, dlProgressPanel);

                    dlFileStream.Dispose();
                    dlFileStream.Close();

                    DownloadCompleted(dlProgressPanel, clickedGridBtn, downloadPath, extractPath, appExePath);
                    break;
                case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to download \"{name}\"!");
                    break;
            }
        };

        await fileReq.DownloadAsync(dlFileStream);
        break;
    }
}
```

If I need to provide any other details, please tell me!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? you are possibly limited to a few concurrent downloads though the same app. If that is the case we cant help you. However like everything in this world you can likely pay them money some how and increase it. but that is speculative

Comment: @TheGeneral The API lacks a lot of documentation, so there's not much to look at. I'm not sure if the limitation is client-side or if it's an API limitation, it's why I asked here, maybe someone knew, maybe I need to set a property somewhere specifying the maximum allowed connections/downloads, I have no clue whatsoever. I'm new to the API and there's really nowhere else I can get help from, other than people who had this problem before, or who know about the API a lot more than I do.

Comment: Might be this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netcore-3.1. Default value is 2 for non-asp.net apps, try to set it to bigger value at the start of your application

Comment: @Evk Thanks a lot, it works! I would've never thought of this lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can set the service's `HttpClient.Timeout` property, which fixed my issue. I still can't do more than 2 concurrent downloads, but this is enough. My main issue was my function raising the TaskWasCanceled exception. If anybody knows how to allow more than 2 concurrent downloads, please comment on this answer! Either way, here's an e.g. of setting the timeout (assuming `service` is your new `DriveService` instance):

```
service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = gDriveUserCredential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName
});
service.HttpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Evk for the concurrent downloads fix. Setting the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` property at the startup of my application seems to work just fine, e.g:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4;
```